# Primefaces ejecutar effect por metodo

Tags: primefaces

Buenas tengo una duda y es si es posible hacer lo siguiente, tengo un formulario el cual ya tiene un "p:effect"

```html
<p:panel id="FormularioUsuario">
        <h:form id="ConfiguracionUsuario">
               
            <p:commandButton styleClass="BotonFullSiguiente" value="Siguiente" update=":growl ConfiguracionUsuario">
                <p:effect type="blind" event="click" for="FormularioUsuario">
                    <f:param name="direction" value="'horizontal'" />
                    <f:param name="mode" value="'hide'" />
                </p:effect>
            </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

El efecto funciona pero necesito que se ejecute cuando el formulario esta perfecto y obiamente esta configurado para ejecutarse con cualquier click, hay manera de controlar la propiedad "event" desde java o que reconosca los eventos del DOM form ya los probe pero no funcionaron o los puse mal.

Comment: A que te refieres que el formulario este perfecto, no es muy entendible lo que quieres hacer, a lo que te refieres es que cuando termines de llenar tu formulario se ejecute el evento que le pusiste a tu botón.

Comment: Correcto, cuando el formulario este completo el evento effect del boton se ejecute de lo contrario no haga el effect.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo tu pregunta.

Paso 1 :

```
/**
*  Crear Clase para Manejar Effectos
*
*/
@Named //o @ManagedBeans
@SessionScoped // o ViewScoped
public class ManagerEffects{
    //Create una lista String con todos los efectos

    //Ejemplo
    List<String> effects = new ArrayList<>();
    //Efecto que sera capturado por el input tipo select
    String effect;

    @PostConstruct  /* al cargar la pagina la clase ManagerEffects llena automaticamente la lista */
    public void init(){
        effect = "pulsate";
        effects.add("pulsate");
        effects.add("shake");
        //......
    }

    public List<String> getEffects(){
        return this.effects;
    }

    public void setEffects(List<String> effects ) {
        this.effects = effects;
    }

    public String getEffect() {
        return this.effect;
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect ) {
        this.effect = effect;
    }
} //fin de mi beans
```

Paso 2:

Vista de usuario

```
<b>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid colunm="2">
            <h:outputText value="Seleccionar Efecto : " />
            <p:p:selectOneMenu value="#{managerEffects.effect}"> 
                <f:selectItems value="#{managerEffects.effects}" var="e" itemValue="#{e}" itemLabel="#{e}" />
                <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" />
            </p:p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid> 
        <p:panel header="Presentacion de Efecto">
            <p:commandButton   value="Mi botton 1"   />
            <p:commandButton   value="Mi botton 2"   />
            <h:outputText value="Efecto #{bean.effect}" />
            <p:effect type="#{managerEffects.effect}" event="load" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</b>
```

Espero que esto responda tu pregunta.

En este sentido, la seleccion actualiza el formulario completo puedes agregar un Id al panel si deseas. y en update agregar el id del panel sin el @form.

Tambien puedes crear mas listas ejemplo: Lista  por eventos, Listas por parametros, y agregar mas selecciones u opciones. Si quieres en vez de usar seleccion puedes usar botones. lo importante es mandar el parametro y actualizar el componente que deceas.